# Issue running energyplus using eppy idf.run()

Tags: python, energyplus

I'm having a problem running the following chunk of code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
i=[0,1,2,3]
from eppy.runner import run_functions
for i in i:
    OA.Economizer_Control_Type = ECT[i]
    idf1.saveas('C:/Users/mdahdolan/Dropbox/Work and Studies/Economizer 
    Study/Python/1A_Small_Office.idf')
    print(OA.Economizer_Control_Type)
idf1.run(verbose='v')
```

and I'm getting this error:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]om/bEI6B.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with the path in the function `saveas()`, check that the route is available, exists and you can reach it without privileges ;)

Comment: The saveas() function is not related to the idf.run() function, each time I try to use idf.run() I get that error, otherwise, the saveas() function is doing exactly what it should, which is overwriting the previous idf file.